# EF migrations and timestamp column, cannot update/run

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an object in EF6 that i forgot to inherit from my auditableEntity class.  This class has a configuration like so

```
public abstract class AuditableEntityConfig<TEntity> : BaseEntityConfig<TEntity> where TEntity : AuditableEntity
{
    public AuditableEntityConfig()
        : base()
    {

        this.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
            .IsRowVersion();

    }
}
```

Now i have updated my entity to inherit from this class and now upon running my code, i always get an error saying

```
Cannot alter column 'RowVersion' to be data type timestamp.
```

Is there anyway i can stop EF trying to set this column to be timestamp, and maybe i drop and recreate the table myself instead?

Answer (score 6):

> **Replace** one line `AlterColumn` with 2 lines `DropColumn` and `AddColumn` in Up() method.

```
        public override void Up()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Cities", "RowVersion", null);
            AddColumn("dbo.Cities", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Cities", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Edit table definition mannualy:

```
   [RowVersion]   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Step 2. Go to NameOfMigrationAdded.cs in Migrations directory and comment this line in Up() method:

```
   AlterColumn("dbo.YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
```

Step 3. Run 'Update-Database' command in PM console

Now it works ;)

Step 4. Return to previous migration and edit Up() method by adding:

```
 Version = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"),
```

in CreateTable( ... ) or AddColumn( ... )

Ex:

```
  AddColumn("dbo.Rows", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
```